# Fullcalendar not refreshing after event drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In fullcalendar, when an event is added, if the user resizes that event without refreshing, the modifications are not being updated in the database. Inserting and modifying is working perfectly.

This is my insert code

```
 $.ajax({
                           url: 'events.add.php',
                           data: 'start='+ copiedEventObject.start 
                           +'&end='+ copiedEventObject.end
                           +'&color='+ copiedEventObject.backgroundColor
                           +'&title='+ copiedEventObject.title
                           +'&cure_type='+ copiedEventObject.cure_type,
                           type: "POST",
                           success: function(json) {
                                location.reload(); 
// I wish not to use this refresh method because then I loose the location of the calendar. The calendar comes back to today's date.
                           }
                       });
 if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
```

This is my update code

```
// load events from MySQL
                events:'events.json.php',

                // if event is moved around in the calendar
                eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                    start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    startTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Hmm");
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'events.update.php',
                    data: 'start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id,
                    type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            //alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },                  

                // if event is rezided in the calendar
                eventResize: function(event) {
                    start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'events.update.php',
                    data: 'start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id,
                    type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            //alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Did you try `rerenderEvents`?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it didn't work the way I wanted. So I moved away from this, and instead when the user wants to create an event I redirect him to another page. It's not fixing the problem but at least it lets me continue in my coding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this, but it doesn't work.

```
 type: "POST",
                           success: function(json) {
                                //location.reload();                                
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); 
                           }
```

It does refresh the page, but it duplicates my event... then if I refresh the page, it works.

Comment: Hey @BAAC can you guide me to achieve the task what you did? becos i also had the same pblm